# mailgun send email to multiple users

Tags: php, mailgun

i have the following mailgun.php file:

```
define('MAILGUN_URL', 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/my_domain');
define('MAILGUN_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxx'); 
function sendmailbymailgun($to,$toname,$mailfromnane,$mailfrom,$subject,$html,$text,$tag,$replyto){
    $array_data = array(
        'from'=> $mailfromnane .'<'.$mailfrom.'>',
        'to'=>$toname.'<'.$to.'>',
        'subject'=>$subject,
        'html'=>$html,
        'text'=>$text,
        'o:tracking'=>'yes',
        'o:tracking-clicks'=>'yes',
        'o:tracking-opens'=>'yes',
        'o:tag'=>$tag,
        'h:Reply-To'=>$replyto
    );
    $session = curl_init(MAILGUN_URL.'/messages');
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:'.MAILGUN_KEY);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array_data);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);
    $results = json_decode($response, true);
    return $results;
}
```

I am trying to send a notification email to end users with the following code:
`$eml` = email address variable
`$usrn` = user name
`$htm` = html text generated from mailtext.php with displaytext function
`$cust_orderid` = parameter,not really important in this case

```
if ((strlen($eml)>5)&&(isset($eml))&&(!is_null($eml))) {
include('./mailtext.php');
$htm = displaytext($cust_orderid);       
require_once('./mailgun.php');
sendmailbymailgun($eml,$usrn,'NOTIFICATIONS','notify@mydomain.com','NOTIFICATION SUBJECT',$htm,'','','');
          }
```

everything works fine, until i have in `$eml`  field multiple email addresses separated with comma.
then i got the following error message:
'to' parameter is not a valid address. please check documentation

i checked the documentation and it tells, that i can have multiple email addresses separated by comma. reference:
[mailgun API documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#sending)

some ideas how to solve this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: Your `to` should look like a bit different if you have a , (comma) separated list of emails. You can't have just one set of `<` `>` you need to have it around every email address in the list.

Comment: can i just ignore the 'toname' parameter? it means i will just post email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com  without < > ?

Comment: _Side note:_ You don't need all the `()` around every expression in your `if`-statement. It could be rewritten as: `if (strlen($eml) > 5 && isset($eml) && !is_null($eml))` which makes it _much_ more readable.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  it will cause a php error.. php must know where is the beginning and the end of the 'if' .. at least in Visual studio code that i am using.

Comment: Please check my example again. I realized that I used "expression" instead of "condition". There is one pair of parentheses around all conditions, not around each. So instead of `if (($foo == 1) && ($bar == 2))` you can do `if ($foo == 1 && $bar == 2)`. You only need to group the conditions if you have things like: `if ($foo == 1 && ($bar == 1 || $bar == 2))`. Afaik, that's no difference from, for example,  C#

Comment: ok now i see, but it not helping me at the moment :D  92 customers waiting for some more serious thing haha

Comment: @FeHora yeah I think you could ignore the `toname`, and let the email clients handle all that extra info for you if they can.

Comment: helped - updating my question with the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a suggestion of @Igor Ilic i modified the mailgun.php like this:

```
<?
define('MAILGUN_URL', 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/mydomain');
define('MAILGUN_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxx'); 
function sendmailbymailgun($to,$toname,$mailfromnane,$mailfrom,$subject,$html,$text,$tag,$replyto){
    $array_data = array(
        'from'=> $mailfromnane .'<'.$mailfrom.'>',
        'to'=> $to,
        'subject'=>$subject,
        'html'=>$html,
        'text'=>$text,
        'o:tracking'=>'yes',
        'o:tracking-clicks'=>'yes',
        'o:tracking-opens'=>'yes',
        'o:tag'=>$tag,
        'h:Reply-To'=>$replyto
    );
    $session = curl_init(MAILGUN_URL.'/messages');
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:'.MAILGUN_KEY);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array_data);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);
    $results = json_decode($response, true);
    return $results;
}
?>
```

the only change is :

```
'to'=> $to,
```

instead of:

```
'to'=>$toname.'<'.$to.'>',
```

now i am simply ignoring the < >  part of the email sending - it's not so pretty with the display name/email address in the email header, but i don't care, it works, even when the email address `$eml` parameter looks dirty like this: `'email1@gmail.com,,,email2@yahoo.com,,email3@office.com,,'`

thanks for the great idea,
problem solved